# PyGame: Why isn't my object moving automatically

Tags: python, pygame

I want 'rock' to be able to automatically move to the left when running the program but nothing happens, from my understanding I have made it so that the rocks x position moves by 3 every iteration

```
import pygame

p = pygame.display.set_mode((900, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption("First game")
FPS = 60
WHITE = 255, 255, 255
RED = 255, 0, 0
GREEN = 0, 255, 0
BLUE = 0, 0, 255
DBLUE = 57, 64, 90

board1 = pygame.image.load("board.png")
board2 = pygame.image.load("board.png")
rock = pygame.image.load("rock.png")


def draw_window(board1_move, board2_move, rock_scaled):
    p.fill(DBLUE)
    board1_scaled = pygame.transform.rotate(pygame.transform.scale(board1, (55, 40)), 40)
    board2_scaled = pygame.transform.rotate(pygame.transform.scale(board2, (55, 40)), 40)
    rock_scaled = pygame.transform.rotate(pygame.transform.scale(rock, (55, 40)), 0)
    p.blit(board1_scaled, (board1_move.x, board1_move.y))
    p.blit(board2_scaled, (board2_move.x, board2_move.y))
    p.blit(rock_scaled, (400, 250))
    pygame.display.update()


keypress = pygame.key.get_pressed()


def board1_move_func(keypress, board1_move):
    if keypress[pygame.K_w] and board1_move.y > 0:
        board1_move.y -= 3
    if keypress[pygame.K_s] and board1_move.y < 530:
        board1_move.y += 3


def board2_move_func(keypress, board2_move):
    if keypress[pygame.K_UP] and board2_move.y > 0:
        board2_move.y -= 3
    if keypress[pygame.K_DOWN] and board2_move.y < 530:
        board2_move.y += 3


def main():
    rock_x = 450
    rock_y = 250
    board1_move = pygame.Rect(20, 250, 55, 40)
    board2_move = pygame.Rect(805, 250, 55, 40)
    rock_move = pygame.Rect(rock_x, rock_y, 55, 40)


    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    run = True
    while run == True:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

        keypress = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        rock_x += 3

        board1_move_func(keypress, board1_move)
        board2_move_func(keypress, board2_move)
        draw_window(board1_move, board2_move, rock_move)

    pygame.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You change `rock_x`, but draw the object at the position stored in `rock_move`. `rock_move` is not magically tied with `rock_x`. You can update `rock_move` after changing `rock_x`:

```py
rock_x += 3
rock_move.x = rock_x
```

However, I recommend changing `rock_move` instead of `rock_x`:

```py
rock_move.x += 3
```